# Can you remove an independent variable that is questionable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, linear

One of the key independent variables is in a form of a probability. The probability is outside the range of [0, 1]. There's approximately 10 of them out of 100. For example, it has 10 values with a probability greater than 1. I am not able to talk to the person who collected this dataset.

When I include this variable into the model, it fulfills the zero-conditional assumption. The outliers does not have a strong influence even though it has a high leverage. See below for the Residual vs Fitted plot and the Residual vs Leverage plot.

[image]
[image]

When I don't include this variable into the model, it fails the zero-conditional assumption. The outliers does have a strong influence and a high leverage. See below for the plots.

[image]
[image]

In your opinion, should I remove this probability variable even though I believe it has an important play in the model?

Comment: what do we understand by zero conditional assumption  ? what is your model ? The summary output.

Comment: what  are your  independent variables  other than probability variable ?  outliers  '?

Comment: The model is similar to this: log(y) ~ x + p where x has a direct impact on y and p also has a direct impact on y but it is a probability.

Comment: good,  what  about outlier and leverage etc.  Are you surely working with a probability variable or the probabillity function ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is a probability variable. It is a probability from 0 to 1.

Comment: Does p represents the outlier(s) ? Your first paragraph is not clear.10 out of 100 with a probability greater than 1 ??  These could be validity coefficients or what ?  If you do not identity/ clarify ,  the response to your questions can not be worked out. Moreover edit your tags. Remove the overlapping/ unnecessary one's.